# The variable 'pminutes' is being used without being initialized

Tags: c, pointers

I keep getting this error message:

> The variable 'pminutes' is being used without being initialized.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void ConvertMinutesToHM(int time_minutes, int *phours, int *pminutes);

void main ()
{
    int min, *phours, *pminutes;
    printf("Enter a number of minutes:\n");
    scanf("%d", &min);
    ConvertMinutesToHM(min, phours, pminutes);
    printf("Hours=%d", phours);
    printf("Minutes=%d", pminutes);
}

void ConvertMinutesToHM (int time_minutes, int *phours, int *pminutes)
{
    int hours, minutes; 
    *phours = time_minutes / 60;
    *pminutes = time_minutes % 60 * 60;

}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you ask, do you understand the error message? Do you know what it means to *initialize* a variable?

Comment: You are using pointer that is uninitialised.Pointers with static storage are initialized with null pointers. Pointers with automatic storage duration are not initialized.

Comment: your question highlites a single problem with the posted code, however, there are several problems, Which your compiler should have told you about.

Comment: `phours` and `pminutes` are both unitialized.  This can be fixed by initializing them to some value.  However, the function: `ConvertMinutesToHM` cannot actually modify the callers' variables with the current code.

Comment: regardless of what Visual Studio will allow, the return type from `main()` is ALWAYs `int`

Comment: do not `#include` header files those contents (I.E. math.h) are not used.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line  3) separate functions via 2 or 3 blank lines so they are easily distinguished from separation of code blocks.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this line: `*pminutes = time_minutes % 60 * 60;` will actually yield the number of seconds, after the hours are removed.  Not what you want.  Suggest: `*pminutes = time_minutes % 60;`

Comment: when calling functions that display their results on the terminal, it is best to end the 'format string' with a '\n' so the text will be flushed from the associated output buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Because you haven't initialised `pminutes` in `main` before passing it to `ConvertMinutesToHM()` function. Remember you need to initialise all parameters before passing them to a function - otherwise how does the function know what values to work on?

In `main` you should really just need normal `int` and initialise them properly:

```
int min = 0, phours = 0, pminutes = 0;
```

In when calling `ConvertMinutesToHM()`, you can pass in the address of the corresponding variables:

```
ConvertMinutesToHM(min, &phours, &pminutes);
```

---

Edit: You made other mistakes, too in that `ConvertMinutesToHM()` function: local `hours, minutes` are completely not needed, and the calculation of `pminutes` makes no sense.

Sample fix:

```
void ConvertMinutesToHM(int time_minutes, int *phours, int *pminutes);

int main()
{
    int min = 0, phours = 0, pminutes = 0;
    printf("Enter a number of minutes:\n");
    scanf("%d",&min);
    ConvertMinutesToHM(min,&phours,&pminutes);
    printf("Hours=%d\n",phours);
    printf("Minutes=%d\n",pminutes);
}

void ConvertMinutesToHM (int time_minutes, int *phours, int *pminutes)
{
    *phours=time_minutes/60;
    *pminutes=time_minutes%60;
}
```

Comment: yes but the program is supposed to get just the minutes and make the clculation to change it from just minutes to hours and minutes i.e. 197 is 3 hours and 28 minutes.
so how can i call the function without initializing the pointers?

Comment: @danielsable I look a bit more at your code. No, you still don't need pointers in `main`, and you got other mistakes, too - see edited.

Answer (score 2):

In the c programming language, variables that are not global or static or explicitly initialized by the programmer are not initialized at all and reading them would cause undefined behavior.

You are passing it to a function that will dereference the pointer and since it was not initialized the function would read from an undetermined location in memory, because the value the pointer is holding is not defined anywhere. This does not mean that the pointer is not holding a value, it means that the value is a random garbage value that cannot be used as an address but will be if you are not careful and dereference it.

You can initialize it by making it point to an actual variable that would be allocated on the stack and make it point to valid memory, the like this

```
int minutes;
int *pminutes = &minutes;
```

of course, you can simply pass `&minutes` directly but this way, the `pminutes` pointer will be holding the address of a stack variable `minutes` which is properly allocated, but uninitialized.

The `minutes` variable is not required to be initialized because it's intended to be used as storage for the value the function will read and store into whatever `pminutes` is pointing to.

The problem is then that `pminutes` is a pointer, and not initializing it will cause undefined behavior when the program attempts to read the address it is holding.

It's still good practice to explicitly initialize most variables, but I also consider good practice not to do it when you are certain that they will be initialized somewhere and adding a explicit initialization would not be meaningful, thus making the code harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You are using pointer that is uninitialised. Pointers with static storage are initialized with null pointers. Pointers with automatic storage duration are not initialized.

From C89 Standard:

> [C89 §3.5.7 Initialization](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.5.7)
>
> If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly, it is initialized implicitly as if every member that has arithmetic type were assigned 0 and **every member that has pointer type were assigned a null pointer constant.** If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

See Also ISO C 99 6.7.8.10:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
> indeterminate. If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly,
> then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;

You are defining `int *pminutes` and not initialising it so its value is indeterminate and after that doing `*pminutes = time_minutes%60*60` try to access that indeterminate location and result in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired operation
3. incorporates the comments on the OPs question

and now the code

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf(), scanf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
//#include <math.h>

void ConvertMinutesToHM(int time_minutes, int *phours, int *pminutes);

int main ( void )
{
    int min;
    int hours;
    int minutes;

    printf("Enter a number of minutes:\n");
    if( 1 != scanf("%d", &min) )
    {
        perror( "scanf failed to read the minutes from the user" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    ConvertMinutesToHM(min, &hours, &minutes);

    printf("Hours=%d\n", hours);
    printf("Minutes=%d\n", minutes);
} // end function: main


void ConvertMinutesToHM (int time_minutes, int *phours, int *pminutes)
{
    //int hours, minutes;
    *phours = time_minutes / 60;
    *pminutes = time_minutes % 60;
} // end function: ConvertMinutestoHM
```

and here is the results that are displayed on the terminal:

```
Enter a number of minutes:
100
Hours=1
Minutes=40
```